# How to capture an image in Android Studio using OpenCV

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv

Right now I have OpenCV imported and working in an Android Studio app. All the app does is, when opened, has the main activity open the camera on a Galaxy Tab and that is it. I want to be able to capture and save images. Does anyone know how to go about doing this or know a link I can follow to learn more about it? Whenever I Google how to capture an image I don't get any helpful info. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Button that directs the user to the camera and when the picture is taken it shows in an imageView.

Here is the code :-

```
 ImageView im =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageid); //Your image View 
 Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Buttonid); // your Button
 b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent img = new Intent (); //Your Intent
            img.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); //the intents action to capture the image
            startActivityForResult(img,1);//start the activity adding any code .1 in this example
        }


    });
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){ 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);//method retrieves the requestCode , its result and the data containing the pic from system  
    if(requestCode==1&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data"); //get data and casts it into Bitmap photo
        im.setImageBitmap(photo);// set photo to imageView
    }
```

Comment: But, is there any way to click the image programmatically (without user's intervention)?